provide something for or to sb
I have found some answers to this question, but they weren't discussed or validated by many people, if any. So, I'll quote them down here and wait for more discussion to draw a conclusion. Whom do you agree with?

Question 1: It is perhaps not easily found by non-native English speakers, but it rather bothers me:

A variety of plants provides natural resources to species of fungi.
Variety of plants provides food resources for species of fungi.

Answer 1: Both "provide to" and "provide for" are grammatical, idiomatic, and common. Neither is wrong, and they mean essentially the same thing. They differ only in nuance: the "to" has a sense of transference. It's neutral. The plants supply food to the fungi. The "for" has a sense of cultivation. It's positive. The plants are invested in the well-being of the fungi, so feed them.

Question 2: I've seen both prepositions used in very similar sentences and I wonder if there's any difference between them. Would they both work in: "The hotel provides shoe cleaning service to/for its clients" and "We provide legal advice to/for our clients"? For some reason I have a preference for "for". What do you think?"
Answer 2: The general distinction is that "provide something to someone" says that it's provided directly to the person concerned. Whereas with "provide something for someone", it might be provided to an intermediary.
For example, a food-product company may provide a range of foods for vegetarians, but they provide the products to a retailer.
In many cases, the two concepts coincide, so either "to" or "for" would make sense. In your two examples, either would be acceptable — and I'd probably go for "for" in the first sentence, and "to" in the second.

"The hotel provides a shoe cleaning service for its clients": I'd prefer "for", because the hotel isn't directly providing 'shoe cleaning' to the guests. Someone is cleaning shoes for the guests; the hotel then returns the clean shoes.

"We provide legal advice to our clients": Here, the advice is almost certainly being provided directly to the clients, either in discussion or in writing.


But it's more of a nuance than an obvious difference.

With transitive provide sth to/for sb, I think answer 2 is closer - to is more about giving or handing off something to someone, while for is more about something being made available to someone. Most of the time it is a distinction without difference, and there's no solid line dividing the two, but there is a bit of a nuance:

A laptop was provided to me. (more likely that someone came to me and gave me a laptop, and more likely that I took/accepted it)


A laptop was provided for me. (more likely that a laptop was available to me upon request, perhaps temporarily, and I may or may not have made use of it)


(the "nurturing" aspect is more applicable to intransitive provide for sb - you'd say you provide for your kids, ie. work and gather resources in order to enable them to thrive)

I might provide a dress to my son for my granddaughter. In such case, he would be the dress’s immediate recipient, while she would be its intended ultimate possessor.
